# Error using model averaging and predicting with MuMln in R

Tags: r, predict

I'm using the MuMln package in R to get an averaged model (http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/MuMIn/docs/model.avg), and predict from that. The package also includes a `predict` function specifically for an object returned by `model.avg` (http://www.inside-r.org/node/123636). I've tried using the examples listed, code as follows:

```
   # Example from Burnham and Anderson (2002), page 100: 
     fm1 <- lm(y ~ X1 + X2 + X3 + X4, data = Cement)

     ms1 <- dredge(fm1)

  # obtain model average for AIC delta <2
    avgm <- model.avg(ms1, subset=delta<2)

  # predict from the averaged model
    averaged.full <- predict(avgm, full = TRUE)
```

But I keep getting

> Error in predict.averaging(avgm, full = TRUE): can predict only from 'averaging' object containing model list

which I don't understand, because I did follow the examples and used an object returned by model.avg. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you create an `"averaging"` object directly from `"model.selection"` object, it does not contain the component models, which are required for `predict` to work. You can use `model.avg(..., fit = TRUE)` which will fit the models again.

To avoid fitting the models twice, you can first create a list of all models with
`lapply(dredge(..., evaluate = FALSE), eval)` and afterwards 
use `model.avg(..., subset = ...)` on it.

Comment: Ah I see. Why does it need to be `evaluate = FALSE`? Sorry, not very familiar with the base `eval` function, does that do the job instead?

Comment: basically, `dredge` with `evaluate = FALSE` produces a list of commands (`lm(...)`) and `eval` executes them. Otherwise `dredge` would run the models once, and `get.models` or `model.avg(..., fit = TRUE)` would run them again. If there is a small number of small models there is no noticeable difference in computing time though.

Comment: I am running into different issue. The function runs but the prediction estimates are just not correct. 
`pred <- predict.averaging(mod.avg, backtransform = TRUE, se.fit = TRUE)`

Where `mod.avg` is a model.avg object returned from `model.avg()` using the `dredge()` function. The output is returning predictions that jump all over the place. The regression strongly suggests a linear relationship.